# jQuery DataTables - colReorder and rowGrouping

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a problem with jQuery DataTables and Row Grouping plug-in.
This is my code:

```
list1table = $('#list1table').DataTable({
  "paging": false,
  "ordering": false,
  "info": false,
  "searching": false,
  "scrollY": 600,
  "scrollX": true,
  fixedColumns: {
    leftColumns: fixcol_count
  },
  colReorder: {
    order: tmp_order
  }
}).rowGrouping({
   iGroupingColumnIndex: 6,
   sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "asc",
   iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex: 0
});
```

Error:

> TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).rowGrouping is not a function

But if I change **d**ataTable to **D**ataTable, `rowGrouping` working correctly, but `colReorder` is not working...

I get an error:

> TypeError: list1table.colReorder is undefined

colReorder must have **D**ataTable, but JQuery Row Gruping need **d**ataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Row grouping plug-in works fine if you use `dataTable()` instead of `DataTable()`, see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/101yfyzL/).

However row grouping plug-in is no longer being developed, I would not recommend using it. Use alternative way to perform row grouping as shown in [Row grouping example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html).

Comment: Ok, my mistake. I tried call list1table.colReorder.reset(); and get an error. Do you have idea how I can call this function if I have list1table = $('#list1table').dataTable(...) ?

I would use row grouping in datatables, but I need Collapsible/Expandable groups.

Comment: @user2971916, you can call it like this: `list1table.api().colReorder.reset();`